# Implement switch case in MIPS

Tags: switch-statement, mips

i'm trying to implement switch case in mips using jump table as an array of labels to jump to:

```
    .data
JumpTable:
    .word L0, L1, L2, L3

    .text
    .globl main
main:
    la $t4, JumpTable      # address of JumpTable
    sll $t1, $s5, 2     # s5 is value of the variable witch we want to switch on it.
    add $t1, $t1, $t4 
    lw $t0, 0($t1)
    jr $t0

    L0:
        ...
    L1:
        ...
    L2:
        ...
    L3:
        ...
```

my question is, is there any way to do this for not sequential variables?(like 1,4,19,40)

Comment: in that case, the only way is compare-and-jump

Comment: u are suggesting that there is no way to do this with jump table?

Comment: yes, try compiling from C and look at the disassembly, not all cases can be used with a jump table. Of course you can pad unused cases with the address to a jump to break out of the case but it will consume memory, and not all cases can use this. For example how can you make a jump table for a switch with 0, 1, 10000000, 500000000 cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add doubles to your table

```
.word L0, L0, L0, L0, L1, L2, L2, L2, L2, L2, L2, L3, ...
```

OR

use conditional branching. It depends on your intended application.

Comment: it only works with small jump tables, for cases with large distance it will consume much memory and maybe can't be implemented at all

Comment: That's true. In that case, conditional branching should be used.